# Photo Upload Solution

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As a amateur photographer, I don't like any of the current free gallery apps on offer, so want to write one myself. Just a simple nice photo gallery with upload, edit, delete etc. I'd like to do it in Asp.Net as I am unsure of other technologies - and it will be based on a SQL Server 2008 DB.

So, DB access, files etc, all sorted. I will do it in a nice layered architecture, probably with MVC and Entity Framework.

My problem is the front end - not sure how to do the multi file upload part. I'd like to be able to multi select the images to upload, and then see them as they progress.

Maybe there's something already established for this? Some fancy Ajax control?

But would be nice to see a list of the files being uploaded, with a progress bar next to each one as they upload.

Is there a way to do this without flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know why you have a problem with Flash it's common used in many applications,
but here is a set of upload plugins in Jquery using flash and not using any.
[example of uploading files without flash](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php)

[here is a list of plugins](http://superdit.com/2010/06/29/10-jquery-ajax-file-uploader-plugins/)

Enjoy :)

Comment: I have no problem with flash - I just have no idea HOW to do anything in flash. I guess now would be a good opportunity..

Comment: You don't need to write any thing in flash , you just have to use it via Jquery that does all dirty work for you.

Comment: Thanks - just tried one, and it displayed 'undefined' where I would expect the control to be - so trying to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 0):

Flash based uploaders are really troublesome especially dealing with form authentication (lost sessions etc). I highly recommend [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). It supports many runtimes (HTML5, Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus, HTML4). We've integrated in our CMS product and it works very well. Also, note that it has image-resizing function on browser-side to reduce both transmission time and ease of use (supported with only by some runtimes).

Comment: You haven't looked in my answer mate.

Comment: I actually looked your comment. But, I especially tried to recommend a single uploader. Because, we've tested almost all uploaders before using Plupload (including populars uploaders which are listed in your link).

Comment: I like Plupload cause it's very easy to implement and use and i think it's the most important thing in plugins.

Comment: I've gone with Plupload as well - looks nice. I am new to using flash items, and am already stuck. I managed to get it uploading images - all good, but once they arrive in the folder, and the upload is complete - I need an even that somehow fires a .Net method to process those files (Save them to correct name, folder and store details in a database). I'm unsure how to fire that method.

Comment: Look at Plupload documents. It's explained in deeply. We're using that technique for our CMS: all postbacks contains both chunk index and total chunks. So, when last chunk is loaded, you can concatenate all chunks to build the file.